# NetworkManager timeout and "ip-config-unavailable" on Ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, home-networking, ethernet, networkmanager

I cannot get this laptop, *Craptop*, to connect to the Internet using the `eth0` interface, but it can connect using the `wlan0` interface.  NetworkManager, managing `eth0`, times out when trying to find a DHCP server (present as my home router, `192.168.0.1`).

A different laptop, *Deltique*, can connect and negotiate DHCP just fine using the same Ethernet cable.

After asking Wireshark to monitor `eth0` on both machines, I found that *Deltique* negotiated  an IP address with `192.168.0.1` after sending a broadcast on `255.255.255.255`, but *Craptop* sent four DHCP broadcasts without receiving any reply.

It seems that the Ethernet port on *Craptop* is functional, since it can detect when I plug in the wire, but why can't *Craptop* receive any packets?

Is *Craptop* missing a driver?  How can I troubleshoot this further?

I've included details on my setup below:

---

## Logs and Command Outputs

### NetworkManager (from `/var/log/syslog`)

- [Craptop](https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tB974mEe)
- [Deltique](https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eN3q2Exd)

### `lshw`

- [Craptop](https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=u1vp8iBb)
- [Deltique](https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KrUyYP81)

### Wireshark: DHCP packets

- [Craptop](https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mUP0MKjp)
- [Deltique](https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sTFFjwVQ)

[image: [Screenshot of Wireshark]]

<sup><sub>Note that [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/45329/83694) is unrelated, since it talks about being unable to connect to `wlan0`.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The probable cause was a defective Ethernet port on the router.**  I didn't find the evidence to support this until 30 April 2015, and I didn't make the connection until 10 August 2015.

### What I Should Have Done

A few additional troubleshooting steps:

- **I should have run `sudo ethtool -S eth0` to see if there were any errors in the network interface controller (NIC) statistics.**

  Since I was able to send but not receive over Ethernet, I might have seen something like the `rx_crc_errors` statistic increment on each receive attempt.
- **I should have tried plugging in the router end of the Ethernet cable into a different router port.**

  Sure, I plugged in the computer end of the Ethernet cable into two different computers, but that led me to believe that a computer (*Craptop*) was faulty because the other (*Deltique*) was able to connect to the router.
- **On the working computer, *Deltique*, I should have run `sudo ethtool eth0` to see if a good link was established.**

  *Deltique* has a 1Gbps capacity, and so does the router, so `ethtool` should have shown `Speed: 1000Mb/s` and `Duplex: Full`.  I would later discover on 30 April 2015 that the defective port would have caused `ethtool` to return different, more concerning values.
- **I should have run a speed benchmark to test the Ethernet link to make sure that I was getting the full performance expected between *Deltique* and the router.**

  Had I done a speed test, I likely would have seen a 1MiB/s transfer speed, indicating a link problem, even on *Deltique*.
- **To rule out a cable problem, I should have tried using a different Gigabit Ethernet cable.**

  It turns out that the cable was fine, but this is a good troubleshooting step anyway.

### Evidence and Explanation

On 30 April 2015, I noticed that my [trusty `rsync -avzHXShPs` command](https://superuser.com/a/926897/83694) was maxing out at about 1MiB/s.  I ruled out other traffic by monitoring `iftop` and by attempting an Internet download on a different computer, which transferred data ten times faster.

I checked the network link with `ethtool`:

```
root@node51 [~]# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 10Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

Aha!  10Mbps at half duplex.  That's not normal and is very slow.  For reference, this was the expected (good) output, captured by switching Ethernet ports on the router:

```
root@node51 [~]# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

The computer and the router tried to [negotiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) [slower and slower speeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation#Priority) until a reliable one could be established.  The slowest one, 10BASE-T half duplex, was picked.

Forcing the full 1000BASE-T full duplex (`ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full`) expected performance caused the affected computer to drop from the network, strongly suggesting that the router didn't want to talk on a faster link.

*Craptop*, which is limited to 100Mbps full duplex in the first place, probably didn't have a chance to negotiate 10Mbps half duplex.

Now that I have identified the bad Ethernet port, all I need to do is not use that port or get a new router.

On 27 July 2015, I returned the defective router after installing a new router.

Today, *Craptop* is running on a fault-tolerant network bond with a 100Mbps full duplex Ethernet connection:

```
root@node52 [~]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: eth0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: eth0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: wlan0
MII Status: up
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 3
Permanent HW addr: 00:1f:3a:55:dc:0d
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 3
Permanent HW addr: 00:1e:68:32:4a:b5
Slave queue ID: 0
```

Comment: Is there a version of this for if you don't have `ethtool`?

Comment: @Hack-R: You can get some of the same information from `/sys/class/net/eth0/`, where `eth0` is the name of your interface.  The [`SIOCETHTOOL` `ioctl()` call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876605/1038828) may also be helpful (and is also how `ethtool` works [under the hood](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool.git/tree/)).

Comment: Excellent write-up that sparked me to pull out the ol' cable tester and test the cables between the computer and the router. Finally narrowed it down to a coupler that I was using to join two legs of the home wiring inside the access console in the closet: only wires 3&6 and 4&5 were lighting up while wires 1&2 and 7&8 remained off on my cable tester. Swapped it out with a cross-over coupler I had lying around and all wires lit up, though in the wrong order since it's cross-over, but I'm betting the auto-negotiation kicked in and didn't even notice. All good now!

Comment: Upon further investigation (https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/55573) it appears the unlabeled, 8-wire coupler I was originally using must've been nothing more than a simple phone line coupler given the wires that were lighting up.