# How do I efficiently move a large, empty disk image to another system

Tags: linux, fedora, rsync

I'm currently trying to move a fairly empty, fresh qcow2 image from one system to another that's far away. I've basically got a fresh install of ubuntu LTS (real size 6gb, apparent size 200gb). Most file transfer methods (rsync over ssh) and sftp with duck attempt to transfer over 200gb.

This is *inefficient* since the disk image isn't actually using 200gb (just that it might, eventually). What would I need to do to transfer *only* what's used by the VM?

Both ends of the transfer run fedora 22, and I'd ideally not want to switch disk image formats, tho that would an option. Speed would be nice - I don't want to trade off transfer time for processing time.

Comment: `tar` the files in the filesystem, and simply transfer the archive.  That's one way to install an embedded rootfs.

Comment: Can you zip it?

Comment: I *think* I tried tar.gz ing it and it took a while. I didn't think of just tarring it.

Comment: Try shrink the image with steps [here][1] before sending it.


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/329287/free-up-not-used-space-on-a-qcow2-image-file-on-kvm-qemu

Comment: hmm. http://libguestfs.org/virt-sparsify.1.html looks good. I'll give tarring, feathering and sparifying a try over the weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rsync` actually handles sparse files.  When you say real size of 6GB and apparent size is 600GB, do you mean that `du -h IMAGE.qcow2` shows "`6G`" but `du -h --apparent-size IMAGE.qcow2` shows "`200G`"?

If so, you can add the `-S` flag to `rsync` to make it transfer files sparsely, meaning that you'll be sending over 6GiB of data instead of 200GiB.

It also sounds like your qcow2 image is not compressed.  If you have the CPU resources to spare and your bandwidth is less than how fast your CPU can `gzip`, you can also pass the `-z` flag to `rsync`, which has `rsync` compress its file transfer as well.

I've got a fire-and-forget hotkey for `rsync` based off of [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/429776/83694) and it makes efficient and preservative file transfers most of the time: **`rsync -avzHXShPs`**

Comment: .... Yes, that's exactly what I mean, and probably what I need.

Comment: the -z flag seemed to work the best. I didn't actually end up using the qcow2 image I transferred, and managed to solve the underlying reason for transferring that image so... meh. Useful thing to know in future in any case ;p

Answer (score 1):

`scp -C` uses compression, which should be pretty efficient for such a sparse file. One advantage is that you'd get a ready-to-use file at the destination.