# SCP vs SFTP for data transfer over 4G cellular connection

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, scp

I'm creating a program to transfer files from a remote computer to my server through a 4G cellular connection, and am looking for some input on whether I should use SCP or SFTP.

I've studied their differences, and I know that SCP is faster, especially over higher latency connections (which my connection will be relatively high).  SCP is not capable of resuming transfers though if there is a connection problem, and needs to start over.  SFTP has much better data corruption detection and can resume an interrupted transfer.

The files I will be transferring will be ~30MB in size, and I could be transferring anywhere from 1 to like 15 of them, so sufficient speed would be desirable.  But due to the nature of a cellular connection, I'm not sure if SCP will work too well or not.  Input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: rsync could be a better choice than either.

Answer (score 6):

Why not [`rsync`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsync)?

It's [fast](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39771), [good on unreliable connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476688/1038828), [checksums transfers](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2612246/data-center/why-you-should-be-using-rsync.html), and [full of features](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

If your data is compressible and network is bottlenecking:

```
rsync -avzHXShPs user@remotehost:/remote/path/to/file /local/path/to/file
```

If your data isn't compressible or your network speed is faster than the compression, exclude the `-z` flag:

```
rsync -avHXShPs user@remotehost:/remote/path/to/file /local/path/to/file
```

If you are doing incremental updates to your destination:

```
rsync -avzHXhPs --inplace --no-whole-file user@remotehost:/remote/path/to/file /local/path/to/file
```

If you are paranoid about the destination's integrity:

```
rsync -avzcHXhPs --inplace --no-whole-file user@remotehost:/remote/path/to/file /local/path/to/file
```

---

### Additional Resources

- [Copy (almost) entire filesystem with minimal effort](https://superuser.com/a/946023/83694) on Super User
- [How do I efficiently move a large, empty disk image to another system?](https://superuser.com/a/926897/83694) on Super User